# Mi login php pdo mysql solo funciona para un usuario

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, login

Hace poco estuve creando un login php pdo mysql, al principio funcionaba perfecto pero luego me empezó a funcionar con un único usuario, o sea me logueaba con un usuario y con los otros no. La verdad no sé qué hacer

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(
    isset($_SESSION['nombre_empresa']) && 
    isset($_SESSION['codigo_identificacion']) && 
    isset($_SESSION['confirm_access'])){
    // si las variables de sesión están ok, al panel
    session_regenerate_id();
    header("Location: ../panel/");
    exit();
}
else{
    $error = '';
    if(isset($_POST['validador-acceso'])){
        //Validamos si se enviaron los datos correctamente
        if(isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
            //Validamos si el campo ingresado esta vacio o no
            if(empty($_POST['usuario']) && empty($_POST['password'])){
                //Colocamos el mensaje de error
                $error = 'Los datos ingresados no pueden estar vacios';
            }else{
                //Limpiamos los datos recibidos
                require_once '../../assets/0/config.php';
                $usuario_cross = $_POST['usuario'];
                $usuario_mysql = 
                    $mysqli->real_escape_string($usuario_cross);
                $usuario_trim = trim($usuario_mysql);
                $password_cross = $_POST['password'];
                $password_mysql = 
                    $mysqli->real_escape_string($password_cross);
                $password_trim = trim($password_mysql);
                //Encriptamos las claves de acceso
                $usuario_hash = hash('sha512', $usuario_trim);
                $password_hash = hash('sha512', $password_trim);
                //Empezamos con la validacion de datos
                $sku = $mbd->prepare("
                    SELECT * FROM comercios
                      WHERE usuario = :usuario
                      AND password = :password
                ");
                $sku->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);
                $sku->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);
                $sku->execute();
                //Terminamos la validacion de datos 
                $registros_obtenidos_usuarios = $sku->fetchColumn();
                switch ($registros_obtenidos_usuarios){
                case 0:
                    $error = '
                        Usuario o Clave incorrectos. 
                        Asegurate de escribirlos correctamente.
                    ';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //Aqui obtenemos los dos datos claves del usuario: 
                    // nombre de la empresa y codigo de identificacion
                    $cfg = $mbd->prepare("
                        SELECT nombre_empresa, codigo_identificacion
                          FROM comercios
                          WHERE usuario = :usuario
                          AND password = :password
                        ");
                        $cfg->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);
                        $cfg->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);
                    $cfg->execute();
                    while ($segk = $cfg->fetch()){
                        $nombre_empresa_usuario = $segk['nombre_empresa'];
                        $codigo_identificacion_usuario = 
                            $segk['codigo_identificacion'];
                    }
                    //CREACION DE SESIONES
                    $_SESSION['nombre_empresa'] = $nombre_empresa_usuario;
                    $_SESSION['codigo_identificacion'] = 
                        $codigo_identificacion_usuario;
                    $_SESSION['confirm_access'] = 'true';
                    session_regenerate_id();
                    header("Location: ../panel/");
                    exit();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nos ayudaría mucho que agregues que comportamiento da este código .... y en caso de fallar ¿qué fallo o mensaje da?

Comment: Para reproducir tu escenario nos faltan fragmentos de código y el dataset con el que validas a los usuarios. Por favor, modifica la pregunta añadiendo lo que necesitamos para poder depurarlo. Y no dejo de recomendarte que, si no te ves depurando esto, utilices un ejemplo más sencillo para aprender: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351152